# How can a pass the values emitted by a ReplaySubject to a array in Observable<string[]>?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Everybody.
I'm working on Angular app and using ReplaySubject for the query terms search. I would like to use an async approach with observable.
My service:

```
export class StateService {

  private busca$Subject: ReplaySubject<string>;
  public busca$: Observable<string>; 

  constructor() { }

  public subjectNewValue(value: string){
    this.busca$Subject.next(value);
  }

  public getBuscaObservable(): Observable<string> {
    return this.busca$;
  }

}
```

My form component:

```
export class FormularioBuscaComponent implements OnInit {

  public formulario: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private stateService: StateService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
      nome:['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  public submit(): void {
    if(this.formulario.valid){
     this.sendData(this.formulario.get('nome').value); 
    }
  }

  public sendData(query: string): void {
    query = query.trim().replace(' ', '+');
    this.stateService.subjectNewValue(query);
  }

}
```

On the component, i want to display all the values of ReplaySubject, and I'm trying to use the RxJS toArray() operator, but it doesn't work:

```
export class HistoricoBuscaComponent implements OnInit {

  public historico$: Observable<string[]>;
  constructor(private stateService: StateService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.historico$ = this.getBuscaObservable().pipe(toArray());
  }
}
```

And subscribe the observable *historico$* on the template:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let item of historico$ | async" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        {{ item }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I solve my problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your StateService, you should **bound** busca$ with busca$Subject:

What i mean is:

```
export class StateService {

  private busca$Subject: ReplaySubject<string> = new ReplaySubject(3); // you can change 3
  private busca$: Observable<string> = busca$Subject.asObservable(); // change this line

  constructor() { }

  public subjectNewValue(value: string){
    this.busca$Subject.next(value);
  }

  public getBuscaObservable(): Observable<string> {
    return this.busca$;
  }

}
```

Comment: This work, but when I try on the component:
this.historico$ = this.stateService.getBuscaObservable().pipe(toArray()); 
I use tap() to debug and the values are passed but dont added to a array.

Comment: The toArray operator will emit its buffer only after its source observable completes. Consider calling complete() on your subject as: busca$Subject.complete(). After complete() call, toArray will emit its buffer.

Comment: If your purpose is just catching emitted values, you can just remove .pipe(toArray()). Assign getBuscaObservable() to this.historico$ directly.

Comment: Thank, you, @okan completing the subject I can resolve the problem of array. Now I have another issue, but maybe this is topic for another question.